# Spring ApplicationListener throwing RuntimeException not caught by @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

We are using Spring Boot 2.x just updated from 1.4 range. Before in an `ApplicationListener` listening for a custom `ApplicationEvent` we would throw a `RuntimeException` that our React.js UI would get JSON back with the error message in the string. We added an `ExceptionHandler` with `@ControllerAdvice` to fix the normal Request/Response paths that might throw exceptions such that the UI would receive it as JSON and show an appropriate UI error dialog with nice message. And many times that message was simply the Message String we put into the Exception thrown.

However, in our `ApplicationListener` code that throws a `RuntimeException` and we put a nice message String in it. The UI does not receive this response/JSON, instead it is a simple HttpStatus of 500 and a general "Internal Server Error" string. Definitely not the nice String we put into the exception.

This worked with Spring Boot 1.x, but not anymore with Spring Boot 2.0

Here is the throwing code in the Listener.

```
throw new RuntimeException("Your account is locked out. Please check your email for reset instructions.");
```

Here is code for generic `Exception`. I also had tried with the same method different name annotated with `RuntimeException`, but that didn't work either. Also this code below shows setting the status to INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. But I had changed it to something else and the `RuntimeException` thrown in the Listener still was a 500 Status, and setting a break point in this method shows that it isn't called ever for the exception thrown in the listener.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
ResponseEntity<Object> handleGeneralExceptions(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.error("",ex);
    return getErrorResponse(ex,
            null,
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ex.getMessage(),
            response
    );
}
```

Comment: add full class. how  use @controller advice

Comment: sajib That isn't necessary. The key here is that this is a Listener throwing the RuntimeException, so it is handled by Spring's RequestMappingHandlerAdapter completely different than say an Exception thrown in a Service class or else on the Thread path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A teammate of mine solved the problem.

1st it is only Listeners and only those related to Spring Security `AuthenticationEvent`

We added a new `Exception` class and a `Serializer` for it.

We also have a

```
static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

And in the `config()` method added

```
 .exceptionTranslator(exception -> {
     if (exception instanceof OAuth2Exception) {
         OAuth2Exception oAuth2Exception = (OAuth2Exception) exception;
         return ResponseEntity.status(oAuth2Exception.getHttpErrorCode())
                              .body(new CustomOauthException(oAuth2Exception.getMessage()));
     } else {
         throw exception;
     }
 })
```