# How to send custom error message for exception thrown from application listener in spring boot in spring security in Oauth2 case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a scenario where i am throwing exception from application listener in spring boot and now i want to handle that exception to send custom error message to user.
As I am throwing "SomeException" and I want to handle this exception and send custom error message.

I am having one ExceptionHandler class which contains code as

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandler{
@ExceptionHanler(SomeExc.class)
ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(SomeExc ex,HttpServlet response){
    return ...
}
}
```

Exception thrown from listner is as

```
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredntialEvent e){

    if(some condition){
        throw SomeException;
    }

}
```

When Exception is thrown from listner it is not got caught by controller advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring ApplicationListener throwing RuntimeException not caught by @ControllerAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735325/spring-applicationlistener-throwing-runtimeexception-not-caught-by-controllerad)

Comment: I tried this thread but they have not mentioned proper implementation so not able to implement it. @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana